# Count elements in list with list comprehension

Tags: list, function, haskell

I'm new to Haskell and trying to write a simple function. I would like to get each element compressed by its upcoming frequency.

For example input: `"aabbcca"` and the result I would like to get is

```
[('a',2), ('b',2), ('c',2), ('a',1)]
```

My code now looks like this:

```
import Data.List

compress :: String -> [(Char, Int)]
compress n = [ (x,y) | x:xs <- group n, y <- ? ]
```

I'm stuck and don't really know how I should count the elements. Any advice?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need here to use another generator in your list. You can calculate the [**`length :: Foldable f => f a -> Int`**](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.12.0.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:length) of the group `xs` here. We use here an [*as-pattern* [zvon.org]](http://zvon.org/other/haskell/Outputsyntax/As-patterns_reference.html) to have both access to the entire group, and the first item of that group:

```
compress :: Eq a => [a] -> [(a, Int)]
compress n = [ (x, length xs) | xs@(x:_) <- group n ]
```

Comment: Now I'm trying to make the decompress function, but stuck with the list comprehension again. ```decompress :: [(Int, Char)] -> String
decompress n = [ x | x <- replicate (map fst (n)) (map snd (n)) ]```
Getting type errors with this code

Comment: @vNSkyline The first thing I notice is that you've switched the `Int` and the `Char`. `replicate` has type `Int -> a -> [a]`, so it can never take the result of `map` as a first argument. Instead of transforming the entire list, you probably want to look at each item individually.

Comment: @Khuldraesethna'Barya Yes i changed it, but my idea is to get the frequency number from the tuple and replicate the character with that number. Is there any other method for that?

Comment: @vNSkyline `decompress n = [ x | (c, f) <- n, x <- replicate f c ]`